# permanently mount Samba version 4 share on linux

Tags: mount, linux-mint, samba, ubuntu-10.04

I want to permanently mount a Samba share on a newly set-up Linux Mint 20.1 system. I'm running Samba version 4.10 on FreeNAS 11.3.

I can **mount in the current session** by running in the terminal ([from this manual](https://www.berthon.eu/wiki/doku.php?id=foss:wikishelf:smb:cifs)):

```
sudo mount -t cifs //net-host/share /mnt/share -o user=user,password=mypw,domain=lan
```

To **permanently mount** the drive I tried editing the `etc/fstab` file. I added the following line ([from this manual](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)):

```
//net-host/share /mnt/share cifs username=user,password=mypw, 0 0
```

and saved `fstab`.

And then in terminal:

```
(base) user@machine:~$ sudo mount -a
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
(base) user@machine:~$ dmesg | tail
...
[ 3680.727542] CIFS: Attempting to mount //net-host/share
[ 3680.727561] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
[ 3680.751016] Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[ 3680.751027] CIFS VFS: \\freenas Send error in SessSetup = -13
[ 3680.751040] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
(base) user@machine:~$
```

We've tried many **other options** in the `fstab` file:

- `vers=1.0,` yields the following error in the `dmesg` log:

```
[ 4583.692974] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95
```

- `vers=2.0,` or `vers=3.0,` yields the following error in the `dmesg` log:

```
[ 4666.975227] Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[ 4666.975235] CIFS VFS: \\freenas Send error in SessSetup = -13
[ 4666.975250] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

- `vers=4.0,` yields the following error in the `dmesg` log:

```
[ 4888.934509] CIFS VFS: Unknown vers= option specified: 4.0
```

- `sec=ntlm,` yields the following error in the `dmesg` log:

```
[ 4160.566932] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
[ 4160.587967] CIFS VFS: Unable to select appropriate authentication method!
[ 4160.587970] CIFS VFS: \\net-host Send error in SessSetup = -22
[ 4160.587989] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

- `uid=1002,`:

```
[ 5923.542766] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
[ 5923.566847] Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[ 5923.566857] CIFS VFS: \\freenas.local Send error in SessSetup = -13
[ 5923.566868] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

- `uid=1002,vers=1.0,`:

```
[ 6195.633461] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95
```

- `x-systemd.automount, vers=3.0,`:

```
[ 6504.718290] Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[ 6504.718298] CIFS VFS: \\freenas.local Send error in SessSetup = -13
[ 6504.718309] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

- `dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,vers=3.0,`:

```
[ 6623.955689] Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[ 6623.955700] CIFS VFS: \\freenas.local Send error in SessSetup = -13
[ 6623.955717] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

We've tried **different ways of accessing the server** by changing the line in the `fstab` file:

- by IP: `//192.168.0.XX/share /mnt/share cifs username=user,password=mypw,vers=1.0, 0 0`

```
[ 5465.946197] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95
```

- with .local: `//net-host.local/share /mnt/share cifs username=user,password=mypw,vers=1.0, 0 0`

```
[ 5848.179532] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the password was spelled wrong.

So inserting either of the following lines in `fstab` will work:

```
//net-host/share /mnt/share cifs username=user,password=mypw 0 0
```

or

```
//net-host/share /mnt/share cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials 0 0
```

with a file `.smbcredentials` with the following contents:

```
username=user
password=mypw
```

No other options need to be specified. In fact for me it didn't work when setting `sec=ntlm`.

P.S. Make sure to replace `net-host`, `share`, `mnt` with the appropriate file paths and make sure your username and password are spelled right.